# spring-mvc: submitting a form when a checkbox is checked

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way to submit a form when a checkbox is checked in Spring MVC?
Basically I have a bunch of input box that belongs to a particular form and there is a submit button which generate run an sql and display on the same page the result. I have a checkbox to generate the result in a dowloadable excel file. When I submit the checkbox it should do a submission but a different url than the form above it?

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated it or an url how this can be done!!
I google on the internet but couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you've written till now?

Comment: Use AJAX to modify the action and handle the request/response

Answer (score 0):

This is a use-case for the `params` attribute: define 2 methods in controller with different `params`. As a value of the `params`, use the name and the value of the checkbox input.

Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers